# Show more error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a textfield with ipaddresses, But it is now allowed to put ipaddress starting with: 127 or 192. I have this:

```
foreach (var item in lines)
{
    if (item.StartsWith("127") || item.StartsWith("192"))
    {
        foreach (var result in lines)
        {
            //lines[result].ToString()
            result.ToString();   
            return new ValidationResult("Some Ip Address(ses) are not correct" + "\n" + result.ToString() );

        }
        // return new ValidationResult("IpAddress cant be saved");   
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IpCondition.IpAddress))
        return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

    IPAddress address;

    if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
        continue;
    else
        return new ValidationResult("IpAddress cant be saved");                
}
```

But the problem is that if you put: 127 and 192 in the textfield you will only see: 127 not 192 as wrong ipaddress.

---

I have it now like this:

```
IpConditionSettings IpCondition = validationContext.ObjectInstance as IpConditionSettings;

string[] lines = IpCondition.IpAddress.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
lines = IpCondition.IpAddress.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var resultsValidation = new List<ValidationResult>();

foreach (var item in lines)
{
    var result = lines.Where(x => x.StartsWith("127") || x.StartsWith("192"));
    if (result.Any())
        return new ValidationResult("Some Ip Address(ses) are not correct", result);

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IpCondition.IpAddress))
        return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

    IPAddress address;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
        continue;
    else
        return new ValidationResult("IpAddress cant be saved");
}
```

But now it doesnt show the error message.

---

And how to have in the piece:

```
 if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
     continue;
 else
     return new ValidationResult("IpAddress cant be saved");
```

The wrong IP-addresses?

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend here. Why do you iterate over the `lines` object twice, once inside the other?

Comment: Bit unclear what your asking. Is `lines` representing each new line from a textarea element? Assuming this is code from a validation attribute, you can only have one error message associated with the property.

Comment: But how to get 127 and 192 displayed? Thank you

Comment: The logic is way skewed here. You're returning the first position in `lines` as soon as you find an error.

Comment: You have a `return new ValidationResult()` statement. As soon as one error is found it returns (i.e. exits your method)

Comment: Yes, I know, but If I do this: new ValidationResult("Some Ip Address(ses) are not correct" + "\n" +  item.ToString()); than it doesnt work

Comment: Can you show some example data & what you expect to see displayed

Comment: Your logic does not make sense. You don't need to loops. In a single loop, build your message, then after it return the `ValidationResult`

Comment: [Here is a simple demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rPOLWy) of how something like that can be achieved, assuming you want to show the user every invalid IP address

Comment: Thank you Chiapa, but how to combine it with the code I posted. See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a linq query to get the invalid addresses.

```
var result = lines.Where(x => x.StartsWith("127") || x.StartsWith("192"));
```

Then return your result using the [`ValidationResult(String, IEnumerable<String>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411880(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

```
if(result.Any())
    return new ValidationResult("Some IP-address(es) are not correct.", result);
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to return them in a single string you can use `String.Join()`.

```
if(result.Any())
    return new ValidationResult("Some IP-address(es) are not correct.\n" + String.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!! very nice, I just edit the post. Can you have a look at it, thx

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible You can add `|| !IPAddress.TryParse(x, out address)` to the `Where()` conditions to return unparsable addresses as well.